# Android parse quote in string

Tags: java, android, string, parsing

This should be a really simple question, but i got confused and something isn't working right.

I want to parse the input string to replace " with [5178] and ' with [5179] which works well, i get the string like i want it to, but when i go the other way, i want to parse [5178] to " and [5179] to ', i get something strange.

Here is my code:

```
    text = text.replaceAll("[5178]","\"");
    text = text.replaceAll("[5179]","\'");
```

That part doesn't work, and this part does:

```
    text = text.replaceAll("\"","[5178]");
    text = text.replaceAll("\'","[5179]");
```

When i input text let's say: `Single quote ' and double quote "` i get: `Single quote [5179] and double quote [5178]` , but when i go other way aroung i get `Single quote ["""'] and double quote [""""]`.

I don't know what is going on, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) use a regular expression as its first argument. `[` and `]` are used to delimit a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) in regex so need to be escaped

```
text = text.replaceAll("\\[5178\\]","\"");
```

Alternatively you could use

```
text = text.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("[5178]"), "\"");
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I thought something was wrong with `[` and `]` but when i put just a single `\\` it gave me an error.